# Winforms: How to Enable Scroll Event Without Scrollbar in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have looked on stackoverflow and have not seen a solution (but may have missed it).

I want to scroll the datagridview contents with a swipe. A swipe gesture in Windows 8.1 seems to translate appropriately to a scroll event which causes the desired result. I can get the scroll event to show up if I have the scrollbar in the datagridview control.  Consequently, to get scrolling to occur in the control with a swipe, I am looking for either (1) a way to have the scroll event occur without the scrollbar or (2) a way to hide the scrollbar. Option 1 is preferable since having the extraneous scrollbar around seems like a bit of a hack. I have a custom scrollbar outside of the datagridview which is why I want to hide the internal datagridview scrollbar.

Thanks for looking and any help you can provide.

Comment: DGV isn't going to put up with you trying to hide it.  So pick the simple solution, just overlap the right edge of the DGV with your custom scrollbar so you cover the one the DGV uses.

Comment: Wow Hans! I am impressed. Your answers are everywhere. Thank you very much.